# t-distribution, what is the value of t*?

Tags: self-study, t-distribution

What is the value of $t^*$ on the $t$-distribution for a sample of size 22, such that the probability of being greater than $t^*$ is 1%?

I have missed the last class where we went over this, so could anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

Look at a t distribution table (found in most textbooks) under 21 degrees of freedom and look up 0.02 for two sided test.  The value you find there is t*. If the table does not contain 0.02 interpolate between the two neighboring values.  Of course this may also be done with a t distribution function on a computer.